# Eclipse RCP: Where to store application data which should be accessible from everywhere?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a `CommonNavigator` which has a `BaseWorkbenchContentProvider` which implements `IMementoAware`. Therefore I'm able to save and restore the navigator's data when the application shuts down and starts. So far it was enough but now I'm implementing some functionality over the navigator's data and I've come to realize I need the data to be accessible *even before the navigator plugin is loaded* (i.e. before the navigator view becomes active).

Therefore I need to change the approach and need to load the data on application startup, display it in the navigator and save it eventually when the application shuts down. Where can I store the data so it's accessible from everywhere? So far I had it within an `IMemento` which was restored in the navigator's content provider but the problem was the data was loaded only after the navigator view was initialized. What is the correct approach to have the data loaded and accessible from the application's startup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the path to a location where you can store arbitrary data using:

```
IPath path = Platform.getStateLocation(plugin bundle);
```

you can get your plugin `Bundle` from the `BundleContext` passed to the plugin activator or by calling:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

The state location returned will be in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins` directory.

It is up to you to write code to load and save values from this location as required.